# Matrix for rotation

Tags: matrices

I am trying to code an AES encryption program. I have a 4x4 matrix of values and I need to rotate each of the rows individually such that:

```
[[A B C D]        [[A B C D]       :  ROTATE 0
 [E F G H]   =>    [H E F G] i.e.  :  ROTATE 1
 [I J K L]         [K L I J]       :  ROTATE 2
 [M N O P]]        [N O P M]]      :  ROTATE 3
```

Is there a simple matrix that I could use to multiply my original to achieve this result?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? It will be nice if you include your approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such matrix. For if
$$
\pmatrix{
A & B & C & D\\
E & F & G & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P } S = 
\pmatrix{
A & B & C & D\\
H & E & F & G  \\
K & L & I & J \\
 N & O & P & M } 
$$
for any $A, B, \ldots P$, then it must be the case that
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 } S = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1}
$$
The matrix on the right is the identity, and has rank 4; the first matrix on the left has rank 1. The rank of a product is no greater than the max of the rank of the factors, so we have a contradiction. (The same argument, slightly adjusted, works for when $S$ is multiplied on the left rather than the right.)

NB: I've use the product-of-ranks theorem here, but there's a simpler argument. In
$$
PS = Q
$$
for $4 \times 4$ matrices $P, S,$ and $Q$, we can say that the first row of $P$, multiplied by $S$, gives the first row of $Q$. So in the equation above, we'd have
$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0} S = \pmatrix{1&0&0&0}.$$

But the same thing works for the second row, so we'd have
$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0} S = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0}.$$

Now $\pmatrix{1&0&0&0} S$ can't possibly have two different values, so there's no such matrix $S$.